# Why does inkscape select vertices I didn't click?

Tags: inkscape

When I edit a path in Inkscape, sometimes it selects an additional to the one that I've clicked.

This will cause me to move two vertices, then I realize that so I have to do undo, click the one vertex I want to edit again to really only select that one and then move it again.

What causes this? How do I prevent this? This is *really* annoying.

Comment: what is vertices? Do you mean node or corner point?

Comment: @thepooran Yes, I mean nodes on the curve. Only know the 3D modelling lingo from dabbling in blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I cannot be sure from just the description, I would suspect you are misclicking, selecting the path segment insted of just the vertex/node. Selecting the path segment basically selects the two neighbouring nodes so they move together.

Another possibility is that you inadvertently scroll your mousewheel while/after clicking on the node, which expands the selection to neighbouring nodes as well (in this case, it selects both neigbours of the selected vertex if I recall correctly)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can select the path segment. That's probably it. It would be cool if one could increase the size of nodes.